# When does Stack Overflow release an API for posting questions?

Tags: feature-request, api

Does Stack Overflow have an API for posting questions or comments?  Everyone else has one, e.g. Twitter, Netflix, etc.

If not, are there any plans to implement an API for posting content?  It can use OAuth or whatever.

Comment: This question belongs [here](http://stackapps.com/).  And no.

Comment: Seems like it would mostly just be useful for people trying to spam the site or to create an SO clone with their own ads that can actually write content instead of just reading it.  I don't see how this would actually be helpful.

Comment: Sites like Twitter are social networks- it makes sense that they let other apps post updates to them ("@SoAndSo just scored 500 points on WordsWithFrenemies!") But what kind of app would post to StackOverflow?

Answer (score 5):

When you ask a question you get a lot of hints and have some limitations to make sure only quality questions are posted.

If you just skip all that and provide your own GUI to add questions to *Stack Overflow* then this would only lower the quality of questions asked.

Comment: You can reject a question post for any of those reasons when using an API easily enough...

Comment: But you are not seeing the *How to ask*-link; don't see the duplicate question list when entering the title; you don't get help adding tags and so on.

Comment: Those help in a pretty small percentage of cases.  And it's not like everyone would use the API even if it existed.  I can think of a *lot* of reasons not to implement this; this is pretty far down on the list.

Comment: Since you mentioned SPAM in your comment earlier I thought of leaving it to you providing that argument (which is a very good one actually).

Comment: Fundamentally what the question is missing is a compelling reason to implement the feature, as was alluded to by David.  Before even discussing the problems in depth we'd need to understand the reason that such a feature ought to exist, and what problem(s) it's designed to solve.

Comment: I could imagine some mobile apps where this API could be helpful.

Comment: @rekire SO can *already* be accessed by mobile.  You don't need a 3rd party application to access the site through mobile.  If there's a feature that can't be accessed through mobile that you think should be then you could make a feature request for *that*, without needing an API for 3rd party tools.

Comment: Your concerns are valid. But check our use case. We display users with possible answers from various sources for their specific problem. When match doesn't score high, they have option to publish their question. About abuse, with the first abuse, the admin can lock down the api key. In our case, we will be taking care of abuse on our side before it gets posted to stackoverflow. That is, the user says publish it and then our dev support will check valid publish and then the dev will publish it. But it should happen with the click.